# How to prevent viruses to hide files automatically in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus

Well, I've read the similar questions and did not find what I need. I use [ESET Smart security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESET_NOD32#ESET_Smart_Security) and I've scanned the computer twice but still "Do not show hidden files and folders" is controlled by the virus. Are there any manual ways to prevent the virus access to this option?

Comment: Can you not get rid of the virus? It's better to eliminate the cause than to work around the symptoms, particularly when malware is involved and you don't know what else it could be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are best to remove the virus, then make system changes.

Use a AV boot CD, boot from it to clean the hard drive of the virus.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

Answer (score 1):

Open up regedit and browse to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\NOHIDDEN` and make sure the Text value is "@shell32.dll,-30501"

Then go to

'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL' and make sure the Text value is "@shell32.dll,-30500"

I would so this after running the system through maybe [MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) and some other AV software.

Answer (score -1):

You can try making up a batch program that unhides files and folders on your drives.

Create a batch file with this text using Notepad:

```
@echo off
echo Showing hidden folders in Drive C:.. 
echo.
echo don't worry, this will automatically close after it is done.
attrib -h -s -r C:\*.* /d /s > null
echo. Done
```

Save it, and name it whatever you want but be sure that it ends with a .bat file extension
add this batch file to your startup programs, by creating a shortcut on the batch file that you have created.

Comment: this batch file removes hidden attribute on the file, any other ways to keep the attribute hidden and showing them?